# Why do some jobs (tech, software dev) require current enrollment in school or recent graduation?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, software-development

In the US for tech jobs I often see on job postings requirements that mention the applicant must be currently enrolled in school or recently graduated (6-12 months ago). These are not internship positions but rather full time positions. What is the reason for this ? Does it have to do with some labor laws ? Is this a not so subtle age discrimination practice ? I don't see why an employer would discriminate based on the fact that somebody attained their degree 2 years ago vs 2 months ago.

Comment: Are these "graduate trainee" positions? Such jobs are common in many industries, and offer training, mentorship, etc to develop staff, while often paying a bit less initially and maybe requiring flexibility, out of hours study, etc (which is easier for the young and carefree). In any case, job requirements are often flexible for the right candidate.

Comment: While I see those types of postings as well, this is for just a standard software developer / engineer level one type posts.

Comment: Are you *sure* they're not internships? You seem to be assuming that internships and full time positions are mutually exclusive, which definitely isn't the case, especially for paid internships.

Comment: The only time I have **ever** seen this is for internship type positions.

Comment: I would assume that are paying a beginners salary and they want to filter out those that won't be happy with their offer.

Comment: Sounds like a typical Entry Level position, though I've never heard of them *requiring* that you be just out of school.

Comment: @DavidK It's pretty common in Australia, at least, though this question's tagged United States.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is from hiring staff copy and pasting existing job postings and then editing them. Even if it doesn't mention internship anywhere in the posting it probably is for an internship type position they just re-used from a normal full time salaried position posting.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of requirements can arise out of several possible sources.

1. They are filling the position based on a subsidy or similar funding arrangement.

Globally this kind of thing comes up in different forms, ranging from direct "Government paying companies to hire newbies so said newbies can gain useful experience faster", to tax breaks or other schemes.

2. They are aiming for "New blood" with recent training in technologies, and hopefully fewer 'bad habits' from other companies that need to be trained out of them.
3. They know they're low-balling on pay, and trying to attract potential employees who are typically more desperate for *any job* and would be more willing to accept a bad offer.

And probably in some cases a combination of the above options would generate such job postings.